# free super class object from base class delphi

Tags: delphi

is it possible to free object in super class from base class?

```
interface

type
  Tbase = class(TObject)
  public
    o: TObject;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  Tsup = class(Tbase)//there will be lot more  classes based on Tbase
  public
    o: TStrings;
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

procedure main();
var
  a: Tsup;
begin
  a := Tsup.Create;
//
  a.Free;
end;

constructor Tbase.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

destructor Tbase.Destroy;
begin
  if o <> nil then
    o.Free;
  inherited;
end;
constructor Tsup.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  o := TStringList.Create;
end;
destructor Tsup.Destroy;
begin
  // let tbase to free  o ?
  inherited;
end;
```

object **o** will not be used in **tbase** class(other than freeing)

**tsup** class var **o** type is different from **tbase** cass var **o** type

is it possible to free **tsup.o** within **tbase.Destroy()**  ? (so i can void implementing **destructor Tsup.Destroy;** )

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

It is not possible that `Tbase.Destroy` frees `Tsup.o`.

`Tsup` inherits the `o` from `Tbase`, but because you also gave that same name to the new `TStrings` field, you can't access the inherited `o` anymore (except with a pointer or cast trick). In other words: **the newly introduced `o` does not replace the inherited `o`.**. It just *hides* it.

So **both versions of `o` are present in `Tsup`**, at different offsets in the object, although only one is readily accessible. `Tbase` only "knows" about its own `o`, and that is why `Tbase.Destroy` **can't** free the `TStrings`.

You will have to implement (*override*) `destructor Destroy` in `Tsup` and do it there. And it should, for good order, call `inherited`.

---

<sup>*The real problem is that the new `o` does not replace the inherited one. They are at different offsets. When code is compiled, their offset into the object is what the generated code uses to access the member fields, so the base class will always access its own `o` at its fixed offset and never any other field, even if it has the same name, in a descendant class.*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As @Rudy explained, the OOP hierarchy prevents the base class to free a member introduced by descendants.

---

I guess the gist of the question is how to use an object declared in the base class as a boilerplate for different types of objects in derived classes.

It is possible to make such a construct, where the derived classes creates their own internal object and assigns this object to the base object. That way the base class can handle the destruction. It will be a bit tedious to code all that and may lead to confusion.

---

Instead, use generics and let the derived classes define any class to the base class object:

```
program TestGenerics;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses Classes;

type
  Tbase<T:Class> = class(TObject)  // Constrained to classes
  public
    o: T;  // Used by all derived classes. 
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  Tsup<T:Class> = class(Tbase<T>) //there will be lot more classes based on Tbase<T>
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor Tbase<T>.Create;
begin
  Inherited;
end;

destructor Tbase<T>.Destroy;
begin
  o.Free;
  inherited;
end;

constructor Tsup<T>.Create;
begin
  Inherited;
end;

var
  sup : Tsup<TStrings>;
begin
  sup := Tsup<TStrings>.Create;
  try
    sup.o := TStringList.Create;
    sup.o.Add('Hello');
  finally
    sup.Free;
  end;
end.
```